# How to choose only specific table as follower instead of entire DB in Azure data explorer using azure data share

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-data-share

I am working on something, where I need to replicate only few tables instead of entire database from the leader cluster. How should I do it in the Azure Portal using Azure data share? I can see from azure documentation, that they are using C# or some other language for it, can we do it directly via Azure Portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, table-level sharing isn't yet available through Azure Data Share, but should become available in the next few weeks (follow this doc for updates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/data-share)

As you mentioned correctly, it is already available programmatically using the management API (documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/follower#table-level-sharing)